# Como criar uma instanciar uma classe usando variáveis provenientes de um retorno de função em Python 3?

Tags: python

Olá, gostaria de poder instanciar a classe `Sala` abaixo usando como argumentos o retorno da função `choose_sala()`:
O ideal seria já chamar no retorno da função a inicialização da classe `Sala`, mas não obtive sucesso até agora.

Segue o exemplo simplificado:

Python 3

```
class Sala:
    def __init__(self, ano, turma):
        self.ano = ano
        self.turma = turma

        print(" Sala Escolhida foi... ")

    def say_hello:
        print("Hello!")

r1 = [] # desnecessário!

def choose_sala():
    r1 = ['8A']
    r1 = "".join(r1)
    print(r1)

    print(r1[0], " ", r1[1]) #para poder usar casa letra separadamente, não deu certo usando a lista normal.
    return r1
```

Gostaria de poder usar:

```
a = Sala(choose_sala())
a.say_hello() # teste da classe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você quer fazer é:

```
a = Sala(*choose_sala())
```

O `*` faz com que cada elemento retornado seja passado separadamente como um parâmetro separado para a classe `Sala`.

Veja mais sobre isso no tutorial básico oficial [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Ok, obrigado, funcionou muito bem, sabia que era algo simples, mas não tão simples quanto um *. Tutorial básico, aqui vamos nós!

Comment: @GeorgeBueno agora que deu certo, poderia marcar minha resposta como aceita, para fechar a pergunta? Só clicar no checkmark verde ao lado da resposta.